# About Angular bootstrapping

Tags: angular

Very basic Angular stuff:

**app/app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<b>Bootstrapping an Angular Application</b>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

**app/app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**app/main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

However, I cannot understand how `main.ts` is invoked when `<app-root>` in **index.html** is met. Could someone explain what happens under the hood? In other words how `<app-root>` fires bootstrapping?

Comment: The bootstrap process loads main.ts which is the main entry point of the application. The AppModule operates as the root module of our application. The module is configured to use AppComponent as the component to bootstrap, and will be rendered on any app-root HTML element encountered.
There is an app HTML element in the index.html file, and we use app/main.ts to import the AppModule component and the platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule function and kickstart the process.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping

Comment: Before `<app-root>` is met, nothing happens and that's what am I asking. How the above element kicks off Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer it point by point.

1. Before being rendered on the browser, the Angular code (HTML markup, CSS, Script - which is mostly TypeScript) gets compiled. This is the Angular compilation process.
2. Angular modules are the essential cohesive units of an Angular application and help us organize our application into cohesive blocks of functionality and provide boundaries within our application.
3. Angular modules provide for a template resolution environment.
4. Now any custom HTML element is also called a directive. This has been the case since Angular JS. Here "app-root" is a directive.
5. Now, your question - how does the "app-root" kick in the process. I will rephrase the question this way - *how does the angular compiler know to replace the "app-root" with the HTML defined by the template*? Answer: When the Angular compiler sees a directive in a template, it looks to the Angular module for the definition so we declare the AppComponent in an Angular module so the compiler can find it. Here there is only the one module, the AppModule, and even in an application with multiple modules, there is one module that kickstarts - the AppModule.
6. How does the kickstart happen? Well, the main.ts file, which is again used by the Angular compiler to tell it which is the first module that gets initialized by the following piece of code

   platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
7. Once the module is known, then the module bootstraps itself, with all the parameters and properties in its declarations, imports and providers.

Hope that explains.